# How can I find the number of regions for a given HBase table?

Tags: hbase

I thought this is easy, but couldn't find any answer. Hopefully, this can be done using command line tools. Or a Python tool.

Or at least find out how many hfiles?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've got a few options:

1 Via HTTP: http://[your_hbase_master]:60010/table.jsp?name=[your_table]

2 Command-line:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /hbase/[your_table]

Found 8 items
-rw-r--r--   3 hbase hbase       1893 2013-05-25 18:03 /hbase/[your_table]/.tableinfo.0000000001
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase hbase          0 2013-05-25 18:03 /hbase/[your_table]/.tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase hbase          0 2014-11-04 06:34 /hbase/[your_table]/045ab87f468ba9e967a0987ca98b7db4
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase hbase          0 2014-11-04 06:34 /hbase/[your_table]/062bc3ef65b9db80a1eeb2c1f4229fdb
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase hbase          0 2014-11-04 06:34 /hbase/[your_table]/0a921049a908dbc929b160210a397632
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase hbase          0 2014-11-04 06:34 /hbase/[your_table]/43a9576bad8845f7d7baacc97882eec6
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase hbase          0 2014-11-04 06:34 /hbase/[your_table]/f492c709d17c4ded150014543f21e362
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase hbase          0 2014-11-04 06:34 /hbase/[your_table]/fa465c6a27023d49893de3c1004efd29
```

You'll get one directory per region (excluding .tmp y .tableinfo):

3 In JAVA you can use [`HBaseAdmin.getTableRegions(byte[])`](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#getTableRegions(byte[]))

Comment: somehow no 2 Command-line did not work for me. I use cdh5.3.0 (hbase.0.98.6) I did not see the table name under /hbase folder.. but no 1 worked perfect for me. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that in CDH5+ they've moved the HDFS directory, use `hadoop fs -ls /` to find the new directory, or, locate hdfs-site.xml file and look for the hbase.rootdir property.